# perl regex match closest

Tags: regex, perl, match, closest

I'm trying to match from the last item closet to a final word.

For instance, closest b to dog

"abcbdog"

Should be "bdog"

But instead I'm getting "bcbdog"

How can I only match from the last occurrence "b" before "dog"

Here is my current regex:

```
/b.*?dog/si
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Regexes want to go from left to right but you want to go from right to left so just reverse your string, reverse your pattern, and reverse the match:

```
my $search_this  = 'abcbdog';
my $item_name    = 'dog';
my $find_closest = 'b';

my $pattern = reverse($item_name)
            . '.*?'
            . reverse($find_closest);

my $reversed     = reverse($search_this);
$reversed        =~ /$pattern/si;
my $what_matched = reverse($&);
print "$what_matched\n";
# prints bdog
```

Comment: @TLP: Does that edit work for you? I figure that people will read the comments too but sometimes I figure wrong.

Comment: Nice thinking out of the box hack! :)

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
/b[^b]*dog/si
```

Match `b`, then anything that isn't a `b` (including nothing), and then `dog`.

Comment: awesome! This works for the example I gave. My only question is now when I'm putting it into my script with variables, like this: ($string =~ /$item_name([^$item_name]*$match)/si) it takes the $item_name variable in brackets to be literal and it won't match :/

Comment: @srchulo You asked for a solution for a literal character, not a variable. If you find yourself having asked the wrong question, you should edit your question.

Answer (score 1):

TIMTOWTDI:

This method can even find multiple matches through the string, or may be optimized if the start or end words will be more common. **Edit:** Now uses zero-width matches to avoid removing then adding the start and end strings.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use v5.10; #say

my $string = 'abcbdog';
my $start = 'b';
my $end = 'dog';

my @found = 
  grep { s/(?<=$end).*// } 
  split( /(?=$start)/, $string );

say for @found;
```

Comment: +1 Nice use of split. Though you can use a negative lookahead instead of `map`: `/(?=$start)/`.

Comment: @TLP, yes that seems to work. Though I believe that you meant to call it the "positive lookahead".

Answer (score 0):

when you don't know already what is the last character before dog this just works:

```
my $str = 'abcbdog';

my @r = $str =~ /(.dog)/;

print @r;
```

prints bdog

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer seems a little complicated if you're just trying to match up the closest 'b' to 'dog', including dog, you just need to make your matches before the term you're looking for greedy. For example:

```
# First example
my $string1 = 'abcbdog';
if ( $string1 =~ /.+(b.*dog)/ ) {
    print $1;
    # Returns 'bdog'
}

# Second example, different string, same regex.
my $string2 = 'abcbmoretextdog';
if ( $string2 =~ /.+(b.*dog)/ ) {
    print $1;
    # Returns 'bmoretextdog'
}
```

Or am I missing something? If you want to change the captured string to match what you want, just shift the brackets.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
~/.* b.*?dog/si
```